# WebLogin not successful using requests in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to login to the following web address: http://healthifyme.com/login/
using requests. I intend to scrap data from http://healthifyme.com/dashboard after login.
I am using following code to login using my registered credentials but login is not successful:

```
import requests, lxml.html
from lxml import html
url = 'http://healthifyme.com/login/'
s = requests.Session()
payload = {
        'email': 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'password': 'mypassword'
          }
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
```

What I may be missing that's preventing the login attempt?

Comment: For starters, you're trying to POST data to a page that's just printing the form - the actual login is performed by sending JSON to the `http://healthifyme.com/api/v1/account/login/` endpoint. You should inspect what's going on when submitting the form if you want to mimic the login.

Comment: To elaborate on that, you should access your browser's developer tools (F12 on Firefox) and check the Network tab while you log in to see the actual requests your browser makes, take note of the URL and params for the login, and then try to mimic that.

Comment: Using the above link, I still cannot access the website. I am just returned to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

After 1 login attempt on the linked site, I noticed that the username and password are posted in a JSON object, instead of a form-like encoding like in the OP. Luckily that is excessibely simple with `requests`. You should simply use the `json` param to `.post()`:

```
r = s.post(url, json=payload)
```